# Static Webpages Served by Gatsby on Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, sanity

I'm using Gatsby for my website (worksetup.xyz) and it is deployed on Netlify.
I run `gatsby build` to build the website.
But when I access it, I can see that it loads the empty page and then makes an XHR request to pull the data and populate the page. This affects SEO.

Is there a way to get rendered static HTML pages?
I use GraphQL queries which fetch data from Sanity.

Comment: Unless you share a bit of code it's pointless asking "Is there a way to get rendered static HTML pages?" because this is exactly what Gatsby it is supposed to do

Comment: I'm using a basic Gatsby template that are available online. Apart from that, I'm running ```gatsby build``` command to build the website. I saw that for all the generated pages, it creates app-data.json file and when the page loads, it makes a request to that file to populate the page. Isn't gatsby supposed to render the static HTML pages?

Comment: Did you check the static content of the page? you can see it using "view source" in browser's context menu